# knockout observables dependencies based on max value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have to observables `a` and `b`.

```
viewModel.a = ko.observable(25);
viewModel.b = ko.observable(25);
```

Their sum equals 50. Changing `a` affects `b` and changing `b` affects `a`. So displayed sum never exceed 50.

```
viewModel.a.subscribe(function(value){
    viewModel.b(50 - value);
});
viewModel.b.subscribe(function(value){
    viewModel.a(50 - value);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5nq9g/
Is there a way to simplify this logic in knockout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your approach is fine, but you could make one of them computed:

```
viewModel.b = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
        return 50 - viewModel.a();
    },
    write: function(value) {
        viewModel.a(50 - value);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ybeQm/

You could also create a function which returns a new function for the subscription so your logic is only defined once:

```
function createMaxFilter(restValueObservable) {
    return function(value) {
        restValueObservable(50 - value);
    };
}
viewModel.a.subscribe(createMaxFilter(viewModel.b));
viewModel.b.subscribe(createMaxFilter(viewModel.a));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T4Hh3/